# why dust is used for money or cash in the American slang?

Tags: etymology

In the American slang, dust can be used for money or cash. But why?

The *Online Etymology Dictionary* [entry](https://www.etymonline.com/word/dust) for 'dust' doesn't mention why it has the slang sense of "money, cash", and [*OED*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/58683?rskey=Xos7t3&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) also doesn't offer any insight into how 'dust' acquired and retained the slang sense (sense 6 of 'dust': "*slang*. Money, cash; *esp.* in ***down with the (†your) dust***").

Comment: Can you provide some examples? The answer is going to depend on how far back the usage goes. Gold dust was used as money during the California gold rush, but no idea is that's relevant.

Comment: @jlovegren: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dust#Noun) actually says that *dust* meaning *money* comes from *gold dust*. They also say that this meaning is "dated." I certainly haven't noticed it; but there's lots of slang I don't know.

Comment: I can't say I've ever heard "dust" used in this sense.  But then I don't generally pal around with mobsters.  But there are a dozen other more familiar terms for money -- bucks, lucre, simoleons, greenbacks, and several others it's too late to try to remember.

Answer (score 2):

I honestly have never run into this as slang for money in written or spoken word. As others have mentioned it appears it could be an old gold mining slang word since you could pay for goods and services (mostly alcohol and prostitutes); of course much of my knowledge on the time period comes from Deadwood.

What I have heard and marketplace.org has confirmed is that dust can refer to a lack of money.

Example:

Dust -- As in "nothing but."

Person A: "Let me borrow 5 bucks."

Person B: "I got dust."